# Why in NPN bipolar junction transistor with EC biasing, if VB increase VC will be decrease

Tags: transistors, bjt

I'm new to this topic. I just study about BJT at school and my teacher said that: in NPN bipolar junction transistor with EC biasing, if VB increase VC will be decrease.

I don't know why is it the case. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please draw a schematic to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Since your English is not that great, please use more words to describe what exactly do you mean! The way it is written, it's very hard to understand your question. And if you can include a schematic, that would help too.

Comment: Most likely your teacher meant a common-emitter (CE) stage.